# Cannot find module './static' when build&run in production env

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autodesk-forge

I am trying to build and run the [Forge-RCDB project](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs) in production env. I work on Windows Powershell, by the following commands:

```
npm run build-prod
$env:NODE_ENV ="production"
npm start
```

but I got the following errors after `npm start`

```
> node bin/start.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './static'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dyang\Documents\forge-rcdb.nodejs\bin\start.js:15:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start: `node bin/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried to do
`npm install node-static`
but the error is still the same. Can someone help me with this? what is the ./static for?

Comment: Do you have a static directory in your project? It looks like something is trying to import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./static` here refers to `bin/static` and is where the front end emits reside after building them with `npm run build-prod`. The error you ran into was not for the lack of `node-static` or any specific dependency for that matter.

Check the console output when you run `npm run build-prod` and verify if the `bin/static` directory with built emits inside are properly generated afterwards. Edit your question or comment below with your findings and I will update my answer accordingly.

Edit:
Tested myself and yes the original run production script missed the `npm run build-server` bit. Will raise a PR to fix this.

So the correct command to run in production is:

```
npm run build-server && npm run build-prod && NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

And be sure to set up all your environment variables before starting as required in the `config/production.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

use `npm run build-server` instead of `npm run build-prod` solves the problem. Not sure other potential effects.

Comment: Tested myself and yes the original run production script missed the `npm run build-server` bit. Tks for finding this out! But you should add this to the start of command rather swap anything out.